# mcrypt and IIS - module does not load in PHP

Tags: php, windows, iis, phpmyadmin, mcrypt

I have Windows 2003 Standard, IIS 6, PHP, MySQL and amy trying to get mcrypt working so I can use phpMyAdmin.

I have uncommended php_mcrypt.dll in php.ini and this file is in my extensions folder (c:\php).

I have downloaded libmcrypt.dll to c:\php, c:\php\ext, c:\windows, c:\windows\system32. I have also found a second version of this file on the next and tried that. After each change I have restarted IIS.

Whatever I try mcrypt does not seem to be loaded when I check php_info();. But there are no errors showing.

Is there another version of php_mcrypt.dll? does anyone have a version of phpMyAdmin that does not need mcrypt? Has anyone experienced this problem / have a solution?

All help will be greatly apprecaited.

Many thanks,

Tim

Comment: When you say you have "restarted IIS" - do you mean just the (virtual) site, or the whole of IIS - changes to the PHP configuration generally need all of IIS (and most definitely the application pool(s)) to be restarted to take effect

Comment: IISRESET at the commandline is the verbage you were looking for @iAn. :)

Comment: Restarting Windows is a bit of red herring - it won't do any more than IISRESET will do too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that the version of libmcrypt.dll I had was corrupt and when I downloaded a version from the net it was fine. As you have already done this I doubt this helps?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue on W2k3(**x64**)/IIS6/PHP5.2.17. Copying **libmcrypt.dll** to **%WINDIR%\SysWOW64** and an **IISRESET** solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your extension_dir in php.ini points to the right path (e.g. c:/php5/ext)
- Try restarting windows after each change instead of IIS.
- libmcrypt.dll only has to be in c:\windows\system32
- To be sure mcrypt is (not) loaded, use phpinfo() to check.

I'm also having difficulty getting mcrypt to load, but above has helped me a lot in getting closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting php from the commandline with *php -m*. It will show you a list of loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a weird issue with Win 2k3 Server + IIS 6 + PHP 5.2.9 + mcrypt as well. As soon as I added the mcrypt (or mhash for that matter) extension, fastcgi just timed out. When I removed those extensions from php.ini I see my phpinfo() page as expected. The really weird part was that I could see the module loaded when I run php -m from the command line.

I grabbed all of the dlls from XAMPP (in the php folder) and stuck them all in my PHP installation folder (C:\Program Files\PHP for me). After making the the change to my php.ini

extension=php_mcrypt.dll

I restarted IIS completely rather than recycling the App Pool and my phpinfo page worked as expected. I am not sure why but fastcgi wasn't able to "see" the libraries in the system32 folder, I had to put them in my php root folder.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my site gave the error "PHP Warning: mcrypt_decrypt()..." 
I use IIS6 - Plesk - PHP 2.5
So, I updated PHP version in Plesk CP to 5.3 and then the error disappeared. 
Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Helpful, but this should really be a comment and not an answer as this doesn't specifically address the question.